# Sampling list of rasters in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, sample

I've been trying several times to sample (Sample tool from Spatial Analysis ArcGis 10.5.1) a list of rasters to a location sample (also in raster format .tif).

Here's the code I've been using, and apparently the problem raised up when Python execute the line of the tool - it creates well all the files in the specified folder:

```
import arcpy, os, sys, string
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Users\Victoria\Desktop\***\***'
inputFolder = arcpy.env.workspace
outputFolder = os.path.join(inputFolder, "sample")

raster = arcpy.ListRasters('*br*')
colony = arcpy.ListRasters('*col_1*')

for r in raster:
    outName = os.path.splitext(r)[0] + "_col1"
    saveDir = os.path.join(outputFolder, outName)
    Sample(r, colony, saveDir, "NEAREST", "Value", "CURRENT_SLICE")
    print '{0} saved in {1}.'.format(outName, saveDir)
```

And here's the error that shows up after run the code:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\Users\Victoria\Desktop\***\***\prueba1.py", line 15, in <module>
    proc = Sample(r, colony, saveDir, "NEAREST", "Value", "CURRENT_SLICE")
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 1617, in Sample
    process_as_multidimensional)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 1609, in Wrapper
    process_as_multidimensional)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 510, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

I'm really new in this.

Comment: You said it creates all files well - could you clarify what the issue is, besides just posting the Python-generated errors?

Comment: Sure! I want to get a table for each sampling item (I'm sampling 10 different rasters to one single raster with the locations points). The aim of this is to extract each NDVI value (which are each of the 10 rasters I mentioned before) from pixels that overlap with my locations. I didn't define the extension of the file in the output cause I read on ArcGis Sample Help Window that it creates automatically an INFO table for each one. Hope that's make sense!

Comment: Shouldnt `in_rasters` parameter be a list of rasters? You are  providing one raster at a time. And `in_location_data` should only be one raster layer or one feature layer but you are providing a list of rasters. Look at the [documentation for sample](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/sample.htm).

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't mention that before: I have a list of rasters with semantical matches (cause all of them are related to breeding season), so that's why I filter them by that criteria `in raster = arcpy.ListRasters('*br*')`. The opposite for `in_location_data`: I'm just picking one raster at time, the one that ends by `_col_1`.

Comment: When you do `for r in rasters`, `r` will be a single raster. If `Sample` wants a list of rasters and you are inputing one raster (`r`) it will not work.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for your comment, it totally helped me solving the issue. It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @BERA](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311925/sampling-list-of-rasters-in-arcpy/360746#comment506279_311925):

> When you do `for r in rasters`, `r` will be a single raster. If
>   `Sample` wants a list of rasters and you are inputing one raster (`r`)
>   it will not work.